# call to unsupported method rsAllocationCopy1DRange in android.support.v8.renderscript

Tags: renderscript, android-renderscript

I was trying to copy all cells of an Allocation to other Allocation in renderscript. From android developer api reference i got this method **rsAllocationCopy1DRange** whose signature is

> *void rsAllocationCopy1DRange(rs_allocation dstAlloc, uint32_t dstOff, uint32_t dstMip, uint32_t count, rs_allocation srcAlloc, uint32_t
>   srcOff, uint32_t srcMip);*

.
The google reference link for method is https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/rs_allocation_data.html

But when i run the script it shows **Call to Unsupported method rsAllocationCopy1DRange in  android.support.v8.renderscript** error

my rs script is below

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.ravikant.rs)
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

int width;
int height;

rs_allocation stateArr;
rs_allocation stateNextArr;

void __attribute__((kernel)) _copy(int32_t in)
{
  int len=width*height;
  rsAllocationCopy1DRange(stateArr,0,0,len,stateNextArr,0,0);
 }
```

and java code is

```
float[] sideArr=new float[width*height};
Arrays.fill(sideArr,1);
Allocation stateArrAlloc = Allocation.createSized(rs, Element.F32(rs), sideArr.length);
Allocation stateNextArrAlloc = Allocation.createSized(rs, Element.F32(rs), sideArr.length);
stateArrAlloc.copyFrom(sideArr);
stateNextArrAlloc.copyFrom(sideArr);

scriptC_copycells.set_width(width);
scriptC_copycells.set_height(height);
scriptC_copycells.set_stateArr(stateArrAlloc);
scriptC_copycells.set_stateNextArr(stateNextArrAlloc);
scriptC_copycells.forEach__copy(stateArrAlloc);
```

Logcat output for error is

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: RSMessageThread
 Process: com.ravikant.rs, PID: 2321
 android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Fatal error 4097,
 details: Error: Call to unsupported function rsAllocationCopy1DRange in kernel at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript$MessageThread.run(RenderScript.java:1313)
```

Comment: have you find any working solution for this ? I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

The bug is right in the logcat. You are not allowed to make this kind of call inside of a RenderScript kernel. You can only make this call inside of an invokable function. Alternately, you can use the Java APIs to do this copy from that side of things.